# Relationship errors when creating Django Custom User Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have been following [this guide](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2013/08/07/migrating-custom-user-model-django/) to creating custom user models in Django. I'm new to Django as a framework, and have become stuck at a series of four errors when trying to follow step eight, in which `south` is used to build the migrations.

The errors are:

```
auth.user: Accessor for m2m field 'groups' clashes with related m2m field 'Group.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'groups'.
auth.user: Accessor for m2m field 'user_permissions' clashes with related m2m field 'Permission.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_permissions'.
member.customuser: Accessor for m2m field 'groups' clashes with related m2m field 'Group.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'groups'.
member.customuser: Accessor for m2m field 'user_permissions' clashes with related m2m field 'Permission.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_permissions'.
```

I understand the are many to many relationship problems, which I believe are caused by the `PermissionsMixin`. I'm not 100% sure about this though.

This is my custom model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=254, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False, 
                                   help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])
```

And the custom user manager:

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        now = timezone.now()

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True, is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now, date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
```

`Models.py` imports:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.http import urlquote
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager
```

I have also created the custom forms and the custom admin bits, as par the tutorial, but don't believe they are relevant to this problem. I am more than happy to include them if needed though.

`Pip freeze`:

```
pip freeze
Django==1.6.1
South==0.8.4
argparse==1.2.1
coverage==3.7.1
distribute==0.6.24
django-form-utils==1.0.1
djangorestframework==2.3.10
psycopg2==2.5.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

`Settings.py`:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework',
    'south',
    'log_api',
    'member',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'server_observer.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'server_observer.wsgi.application'

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-GB'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

# Where to look for templates

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),
)

# Custom user model

#AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'member.CustomUser'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'server_observer',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1'
    }
}
```

I have tried setting `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'member.CustomUser'` to `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'` as well.

I'm stuck, having spend far to long on this last night already. I'd be deeply grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: I'd say AUTH_USER_MODEL is the problem here, it should definitely point to your CustomUser, which should prevent auth.User from ever being created.

Comment: I have an API running in a production environment, so ideally I'd like to be able to migrate to the new user model without dropping any records.

Comment: The API uses foreign keys to associate itself with each user. Is there no way to migrate all of this to a new user model?  It's not the end of the world if I do have to drop it, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: Not sure what your comments have to do with my reply. As that migration doc you linked to states, as long as your foreignkeys point to AUTH_USER_MODEL, you should be fine.

Comment: @DanielGroves This is another question entirely :). IMHO you have some options like dumping the user table and reloading it in the new one, or try some cruft with South (create a user with the same fields as the default auth.User, migrate, change fields around, migrate again...). I'd go with the dump/reload method :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for you help. I'd just been toying with the area of dumping and reloading the data anyway, so I'll go down that route.

Answer (score 2):

You must declare `AUTH_USER_MODEL` on your settings.py. In your case:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'member.customuser'
```